# C++ boost graph : how to add_vertex via iteration

Tags: c++, boost, graph, iteration

I have a large .json file with vertex information parsed and allocated into memory with heavy use of pointers. For simplification, let's say I have a vector of vertex labels, for ex.:

```
vector<string> vertices = {'A', 'B', 'C'}; //assume it is much longer
```

How can I pass this vector in as vertices for my boost graph via iteration AND without creating a unique vector_descriptor for each vertex?

**What I want to avoid:**

```
using namespace boost;
struct Vertex {string label};
struct Edge {double weight};

typedef adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, bidirectionalS, Vertex, Edge> Graph;
typedef graph_traits < Graph >::vertex_descriptor vertex_t;
typedef graph_traits < Graph >::edge_descriptor edge_t;
Graph g;

// manual generation of each vertex
vertex_t a = add_vertex(g); g[a].label = 'A'; 
vertex_t b = add_vertex(g); g[b].label = 'B'; 
vertex_t c = add_vertex(g); g[c].label = 'C'; 

add_edge(a,b,g); // reference to vertices by vertex_descriptor
add_edge(a,c,g);
```

**What I would like:**

```
using namespace boost;
typedef adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, bidirectionalS, Vertex, Edge> Graph;
Graph g;

vector<string> vertices = {'A', 'B', 'C'}; //assume it is much longer
for (i=0; i<vertices.size(); i++) { // iterating thru 'long' vector
    add_vertex(vertices.at(i), g); // no unique vertex descriptor per vertex
}

add_edge('A', 'B', g); // reference to vertex label
add_edge('A', 'C', g);
```

**What I have tried:**
But my trouble with this approach, is converting the vector to enum type. Or finding a way to append to enum type, to correspond to my desired to iterate because of my large # of vertices.

```
using namespace boost;
typedef adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, bidirectionalS, Vertex, Edge> Graph;
Graph g;

enum {A, B, C};
add_edge(A, B, g); // reference to vertex label
add_edge(A, C, g);
```

**Note:** I would appreciate suggestions and explanations to accommodate your solution. I am a C++ beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestion:

> 1. use vector to store vertex_t

```
vector<string> vertices = {"A", "B", "C"}; //assume it is much longer
vector<vertex_t> vtx;
for (i=0; i<vertices.size(); i++) { // iterating thru 'long' vector
    vertex_t tmp = add_vertex(g);
    g[tmp].label = vertices.at(i);
    vtx.push_back(tmp); // no unique vertex descriptor per vertex
}

add_edge(vtx[0], vtx[1], g); // reference to vertices by vertex_descriptor
add_edge(vtx[0], vtx[2], g);
```

Does this what you want?

> 2. use map or unordered map to convert above

```
vector<string> vertices = {"A", "B", "C"}; //assume it is much longer
unordered_map<string, vertex_t> vtx;
for (i=0; i<vertices.size(); i++) { // iterating thru 'long' vector
    vertex_t tmp = add_vertex(g);
    g[tmp].label = vertices.at(i);
    vtx.emplace(vertices.at(i), tmp); // no unique vertex descriptor per vertex
}

add_edge(vtx["A"], vtx["B"], g); // reference to vertices by vertex_descriptor
add_edge(vtx["A"], vtx["C"], g);
```

Does this what you want?

For use unordered_map, you need to `#include <unordered_map>`

Comment: Yes, option#2 worked great!! thanks! (the only edit necessary, and behalf of my mistake, is `tmp.label = ` should be `g[tmp].label = ` )